# How I chage the DropKick.js default fade-in effect?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I just want to show() it, I don't want the fadeIn() effect, how I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to edit DropKick.js and replace the

```
.fadeIn(settings.startSpeed);
```

with

```
.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could set the startSpeed which controls the fade in time to zero, which basically has the same effect as `.show()`

`$("select").dropkick({startSpeed:0});`